# Discontinuous Lines

Tags: qgis, borders

[image]

For so long, I have been trying to create a map with lines of the width of a single pixel, like the one above.

[image]

...But what I end up getting every attempt is what looks like the above map, with cuts in the lines here and there. **My workflow: Project > New Print Layout > Export as Image > Disable Anti-aliasing**

So... I was wondering if there is a way to prevent those cuts and make hairline borders more continuous.

Comment: How do you disable anti-aliasing? Is it in a setting somewhere? I've looked...

Comment: Oh, you have the option to keep it or not when you export a map through the new print layout option (under Project).

Comment: Ah okay, want to edit your Q and expand on your workflow a bit? Are you exporting to PDF or PNG? Etc etc?

Comment: I will do so in a bit!

Comment: I just did, let me know if you need any other information from me.

Comment: Is disabling anti-aliasing not the cause of the issue? What does it look like with anti-aliasing enabled?

Comment: Enabling anti-aliasing does result in clear lines, but since I am trying to produce an editable map, I have to disable it...

Comment: I had a quick attempt at replicating this but my lines always looked okay. Can you share some data and a QGIS project that shows this behaviour, because it might be the way you are styling your lines or some setting in the project.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Apparently, all of the files I tried have the same problem... May I ask which version of QGIS you are using (I am using 3.24.2, for Windows)?

Comment: Also, I used hairline for the stroke width.